# Mixing Plain text with click handlers in Angular template

Tags: html, angular, angular-pipe

I currently have a string that requires plain text as well as a mixture of two faux-links that need to be clickable in order to open modals.

Suppose my string is: *The quick **brown** fox jumps over the **lazy** dog.*

Where **brown** and **lazy** will be faux-links with click handlers. (I say faux because they are not links in the sense of being anchor tags, but rather, spans with (click) handlers).

In order to achieve this, I had some rather smelly (at least I thought so) code that looked something like:

```
<span>The quick</span>
<span (click)="onClickBrown()">brown</span>
<span>fox jumps over the</span>
<span (click)="onClickLazy()">lazy</span>
<span>dog.</span>
```

I was thinking if there were a more elegant way of handling this that maybe Angular natively incorporates, or if there some pipe I can create to do something like:

```
<span>The quick {{ brown | methodPipe: onClickBrown }} fox jumped over the {{ lazy | methodPipe: onClickLazy }} dog.</span>
```

Thoughts, ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep It Simple. The original HTML is what I would expect to see in the template. This isn't really an Angular issue. If you were just using JavaScript and HTML the code would look about the same.